Is it true that $\sigma_{ac}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{ac}(T_j)}$?
Let $(H_j)_{j \in \mathbb N}$ be Hilbert spaces and define self-adjoint operators $T_j : \mathcal D(H_j) \to H_j$. Define the operator $T = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j$ on $\mathcal D(T) = \{(\phi_j)_{j \in \mathbb N} \in \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty \mathcal D(H_j) : \sum_j \lVert T_j \phi_j\rVert^2 < \infty\}$. Write $\sigma_{ac}$ for the absolutely continuous spectrum. It is standard that $\sigma(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma(T_j)}$. Is it true that $\sigma_{ac}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{ac}(T_j)}$?

This is related https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2012/210/otkun.pdf but not the ac part, if I recall correctly.

@Steen82 thanks, this was the only paper I could find in this sort of direction - but I'm looking for a result on the absolutely continuous spectrum specifically. Hoping to also find results on the singular and pure point spectrums as well just for future reference. My supervisor recalls seeing results along these lines before, (specifically he thinks $\sigma_{ac}(T_j) \subseteq \sigma_{ac}(T)$ is definitely true) so I hope he's not misremembering and this isn't somehow open or very dependent on the $T_j$.

I think I'm confident enough in these proofs which follow from $\sigma(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma(T_j)}$.

Theorem 1: $\sigma_{ac}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{ac}(T_j)}$

For brevity write $T = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j$. Write for $z \in \rho(A)$ and $\phi \in H = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H_j$:
$$\langle R_T(z) \phi, \phi\rangle = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \langle R_{T_j}(z) \phi_j, \phi_j\rangle = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} \frac 1 {\lambda - z} d \mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}(\lambda)$$
where $\mu_{\bullet}^{(j)}$ are the spectral measures associated with $T_j$. Writing out the LHS we have:
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac 1 {\lambda - z} d \mu_\phi(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac 1 {\lambda - z} d \left(\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}\right)(\lambda)$$
Hence we have:
$$\mu_\phi = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$$
We can now easily see, since each measure is positive, that $\mu_\phi$ is absolutely continuous iff each $\mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$ is. Hence $H^{(ac)}$ (the absolutely continuous component of $H$ with respect to $T$) is equal to the direct sum $\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(ac)}_j$, where $H^{(ac)}_j$ is the absolutely continuous component of $H_j$ with respect to $T_j$.
Now we have $T \mid_{H^{(ac)}} = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j \mid_{H^{(ac)}_j}$. Taking the spectrum of both sides we get $\sigma(T \mid_{H^{(ac)}}) = \sigma(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j \mid_{H^{(ac)}_j}) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma(T_j \mid_{H^{(ac)}_j})}$. By the definition of the absolutely continuous spectrum we conclude that $\sigma_{ac}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{ac}(T_j)}$.

Theorem 2: $\sigma_{sc}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{sc}(T_j)}$

Again we have:
$$\mu_\phi = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$$
If each $\mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$ is concentrated on some Lebesgue null set $B_j$, then $\mu_\phi$ is concentrated on $\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty B_j$, which is also a Lebesgue null set. Conversely, if $\mu_\phi$ is concentrated on a Lebesgue null set $B$ then so is every $\mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$. So $\mu_\phi$ is singular iff each $\mu_{\phi_j}^{(j)}$ is and we have $H^{(sc)} = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(sc)}_j$ and the rest of the proof is identical as above.

Theorem 3: $\sigma_{pp}(\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty T_j) = \overline {\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \sigma_{pp}(T_j)}$

$H^{(pp)}$ is the orthogonal complement of $H^{(ac)} \oplus H^{(sc)} = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(ac)}_j \oplus \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(sc)}_j$ which from $H = \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(ac)}_j \oplus \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(sc)}_j \oplus \bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(pp)}_j$ is precisely $\bigoplus_{j = 1}^\infty H^{(pp)}_j$.
